# Cant apply flask db migrate when using PyODBC w/ SQL Server. Error: Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied (0). Connecting via pyodbc.connect works

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc, flask-sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to use Flask SQLAlchemy to connect to a SQL database hosted on Azure. Everything works when I use `pyodbc.connect` directly, like so:

```py
import pyodbc
# I got the ODBC connection string directly from Azure's connection strings for the db.

odbc_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:sql-server-for-capstone.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MastersCapstone;Uid={my username};Pwd={my super secure password here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'
conn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_string)
# Works!
```

But when I try to connect using Flask SQLAlchemy, I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The config I am using to connect via SQLAlchemy looks like this:

```py
odbc_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:sql-server-for-capstone.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MastersCapstone;Uid={my username};Pwd={my super secure password here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(odbc_string)
sqlalchemy_db_uri = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}"
class Config:
    # Database
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = sqlalchemy_db_uri
```

And then I initialize the app like so in the directory's `__init__.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from src.python.server.config import Config


db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate(compare_type=True)


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    with app.app_context():
        from src.python.server import routes, models
        return app
```

Finally, I get the error when I run the following in the terminal:

```
flask db migrate
```

Please note that everything worked fine when I was using a PostgreSQL database. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I'm pretty stuck!

Additional info:
Output from running `odbcinst -j` in the terminal:

```
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/jordan/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Entire stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 303, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 238, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py", line 89, in migrate
    _migrate(directory, message, sql, head, splice, branch_label, version_path,
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 96, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 210, in migrate
    command.revision(config, message, autogenerate=True, sql=sql,
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 214, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 184, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 96, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "migrations/env.py", line 81, in run_migrations_online
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2218, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 103, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2317, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2288, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1554, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 303, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 238, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/Users/jordan/Coding/survey-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by workaround.

I edited `migrations/env.py` file:

```
import os
import urllib

DB_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get("ENV_DB_CREDENTIALS")
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % urllib.parse.quote_plus(DB_CREDENTIALS)
)

config.set_main_option(
    "sqlalchemy.url",
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI.replace("%", "%%"),
)
```

I also read somewhere `Trusted_Connection=Yes` is issue some reason, not sure why.